# Why is my class component not rendering correctly?

Tags: reactjs, render

I've been at this awhile and I can't get my head around it. I feel so stupid. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

The console log works currently, and the console.log of the Object states that the state has been updated from false to true.

```
class ChoiceBar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      handleFirstQuestion: false,
    };
    this.handleFirstQuestion = this.handleFirstQuestion.bind(this)
  }

  handleFirstQuestion() {
    console.log("Start Rendering First Question")
    this.setState({handleFirstQuestion: true}, () => {console.log(this.state);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
            <div>
              <button onClick={this.handleFirstQuestion.bind(this)}> Start! </button>
              <p> </p>
              {this.state.handleFirstQuestion
                ? <FirstQuestionBox />
                : null
              }
            </div>
        </center>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: <button onClick={this.handleFirstQuestion}> Start! </button> try this bro

Comment: you should not set name and function with same name like this, it look confusing :<

Comment: What exactly is the rendering issue? Copied into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-my-class-component-not-rendering-correctly-lxusq) and the code basically works (removed the second `this` binding).

Comment: Thanks Drew and Ahn, removing that second bind did help. I checked your codesandbox, and yeah, it did work! I cut it out of my question, but 'FirstQuestionBox' is supposed to be another component. Adding the 'const FirstQuestionBox' but in my full code with a 2nd class component it doesn't render... that might be a wider issue on my end. Thanks for your help though!!

Comment: Well, yes, I did need to stub that component since it wasn't included in your snippet. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue you have that we can inspect and debug live? Feel free to fork the sandbox I shared and add in your extra code.

Comment: Hi Drew, I'm alright. I realized the problem was on my end... I added in css rules on the render that made it invisible. Truly stupid of me. Thanks for all your help for the first part!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you are binding the function twice, one in constructor and one in onClick event handler.
Second pass props component in constructor and super

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      handleFirstQuestion: false,
    };
    this.handleFirstQuestion = this.handleFirstQuestion.bind(this)
  }

return (
  <div>
    <center>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleFirstQuestion}> Start! </button>
          <p> </p>
          {this.state.handleFirstQuestion
            ? <FirstQuestionBox />
            : null
          }
        </div>
    </center>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you are exporting the class component

write this after the class component

```
export default ChoiceBar;
```

you should probably use aero functions and useState hook instead of the class component

for example:

```
const ChoiceBar = () => {
    const [handleFirstQuestion, setHandleFirstQuestion] = useState(false)
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't matter for the problem if a functional or class component is used. It's more a question of personal preference